# DocxTemplate Python

Tags: python

i have a script in python 3.7.0:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from docx import Document


template_document = DocxTemplate(TDR_LLD_template)
requirement = Document(HLD_input)


requirement_table_cell = requirement.tables[5].cell(j,i).text
template_document.tables[7].cell(j,i).text = requirement_table_cell
```

I get : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to give more info, without more info the error simply shows that it cannot open/read your document.

Comment: Btw, the usage of `DocxTemplate` is different from `docx`, you should read [this](https://docxtpl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: What are `HLD_input` and `TDR_LLD_template`? Do you ever check the value of `requirement` or `template_docmument`? Which one is giving the error?